# Get the table's foreign keys in knex

Tags: knex.js

Is there a way of getting all foreign keys for a column with knex? I checked `columnInfo` but that doesn't return the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knex does not support that.

You need to use https://github.com/knex/knex-schema-inspector additional library to query more information about the schema.

The library was initiated from a knex feature request, tp which I recommended to not implement in in knex, but as a separate package and looks like its contributors has been really active ever since.

Comment: Wow! This is just perfect! Thank you for your answer!